# MariaDB - MySQL GRANT permissions to table names not matching pattern

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, database-permissions

I'm using MariaDB. I have a set of entity tables like order, inventory etc and other audit tables order_audit, inventory_audit to track any changes made to the original tables. I do not want to allow database user that is being used by the Java application to have `DELETE` or `UPDATE` permissions on audit tables.

I could assign permissions in following way

```
grant select,insert,update,delete on my_db_name.* to 'my_app_db_user';
```

But the above query grants update and delete permissions to audit tables as well. I did a quick search and figured its not possible to use patterns on table names in MySQL.

Most of the solutions suggest using a different database for such tables that require different permissions. But since my audit tables belong to original tables, I don't like them in a separate database. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: The easiest way would I would do it would be with a UI if possible.  I grant all and then get the revoke script for the audit tables via the ui so you can save it in an external script.  Otherwise it would be fairly manual...

Comment: I am using liquibase for releases. So this is not an option.